# Compare Date and Time in Java

Tags: java, android, date, time

how to compare three date/time values in java?

Currently i use Date objects

I mean:
Date1 - today, 10:00PM
Date2 - tomorrow, 5:00AM
Date3 - current time

Is date3 between date1 and date2, respect date AND time?

```
date1.compareTo(date3) * date2.compareTo(date3) > 0
```

and

```
date1.after(date3) && date2.before(date3)
```

are not working.

I use this code in Android App, and if i set my time to 11.30AM, it still returns true for above conditions. If i use Time-objects and 2nd method, it doesn't recognise my time span is between 2 days.

Any idea?

EDIT: To make it exact, here is my current code. app is something like an alarm clock.

```
            // Current Date/Time
        Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

        // Time when user goes to bed (current day)
        Date sleep = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), Shours, Sminutes);

        // Time when user wakes up (next day)
        // Get Next Day's Date and set Time
        Calendar wk = Calendar.getInstance();
        wk.setTime(sleep);
        wk.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Whours);
        wk.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Wminutes);
        // tomorrow
        wk.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        // and convert to date
        Date wake = wk.getTime();

        // Compare
        if(now.after(sleep) && now.before(wake)) {
                Log.d("uSleep", "Debug: Night time");
        }
        else {
            Log.d("uSleep", "Debug: Day Time");
        }
```

Maybe it's still too hard to understand. Image you go to bed at 10PM and you get up at 5AM. Now how to find out if you're sleeping by comparing your "go to bed"-time and you "get up"-time to the current time. I need to use "tomorrow" for your "get up"-time, otherwise java seems to compare all times for the same day, which is impossible.

Comment: You're saying date/time comparison in Java is fundamentally broken? I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It doesn't help that "today" isn't a point in time. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would make it a lot easier to help you. It's also not clear *how* you're using `Time` objects...

Comment: "Is it now later than 10pm but earlier than 5am next day"

Comment: If `date2` is tomorrow, why you're testing if it is `before` `date3`?

Comment: @Tom the time is important for me

Comment: @DaveNewton I added exact code

Comment: @Xorg If you want to test `date1 < date3 < date2`, then you should use `date1.before(date3)` and `date2.after(date3)`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I added exact code

Comment: You claim that it fails when using the `Time` class - but your code doesn't appear to *use* the `Time` class. (It's also not a complete program... it would be really helpful if you'd try to reproduce this as a desktop Java console app, if possible.)

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Interval.of( 
    start , 
    stop 
).contains( 
    ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
                 .toInstant() 
)
```

## Details

The question is confusing, but seems to be…

> How do I tell if a particular moment occurs within a span of time?

## java.time

> I mean: Date1 - today, 10:00PM Date2 - tomorrow, 5:00AM Date3 - current time

A time zone is crucial in determining “today” and “tomorrow”. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
```

To get the same date with another time-of-day, extract `LocalDate`. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone. Specify desired time-of-day with `LocalTime`. Combine with `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
LocalDate today = now.toLocalDate() ;
LocalTime tenPm = LocalTime.of( 22 , 0 ) ;  // 10 PM is 22:00.
ZonedDateTime tenPmToday = ZonedDateTime.of( today , tenPm , z ) ;
```

To get tomorrow, add one day to today's date.

```
LocalDate tomorrow = ld.plusDays( 1 ) ;
LocalTime fiveAm = LocalTime.of( 5 , 0 ) ;
ZonedDateTime fiveAmTomorrow = ZonedDateTime.of( tomorrow ,fiveAm , z ) ;
```

### Compare

To compare, call the `isBefore`, `isEqual`, and `isAfter` methods.

```
Boolean contains = ( ! now.isBefore( tenPmToday ) ) && now.isBefore( fiveAmTomorrow ) ;
```

Of course, now will *always* be before tomorrow, so I'm not sure of your intentions here.

### `org.threeten.extra.Interval`

You may find the [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class useful for this work, from the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project listed below. This class stores a pair of `Instant` objects, and has some handy comparison methods such as `contains`.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Interval interval = Interval.of( tenPmToday.toInstant() , fiveAmTomorrow.toInstant() ) ;
Boolean contains = interval.contains( now.toInstant() ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

## Joda-Time

**Update:** the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

The best way is to use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, rather than the java.util.Date/.Calendar classes which are notoriously troublesome, confusing, and flawed.

### Span Of Time

In Joda-Time you can represent a span of time in three ways: Interval, Period, and Duration. In this case, we need [`Interval`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html), defined by a pair of specific points in the timeline, with the half-open `[)` approach where the beginning is inclusive and the ending exclusive.

The pair of specific points, as well as the current moment now, are all represented by the [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class. Unlike a java.util.Date, a DateTime knows its own assigned time zone. If unspecified, the JVM’s current default time zone will be applied. So generally better to specify.

### Example Code

Some example code using Joda-Time 2.5.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime now = DateTime.now( zone );
DateTime bedtime = now.withTime( 22, 0, 0, 0 );  // Today’s bedtime. May be past, future, or this very moment now.
DateTime risetime = bedtime.plusHours( 7 ); // 05:00 next morning.
Interval sleepInterval = new Interval( bedtime, risetime ); 
boolean asleep = sleepInterval.contains( now );  // Half-Open "[)" comparison, beginning is inclusive, ending exclusive.
```